# Unit tests for R functions that are not exported

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I am quite new to unit testing, and I would like to implement some simple unit tests for the functions of an R package. The problem is that most functions of this R package are currently *not* exported, so that most of unit tests will concern R functions that are not mentioned in the `NAMESPACE` file.
This concerns the following R package : https://gitlab.com/f.santos/anthropmmd/tree/devel

I am using `testthat`, and when I try to test an R function that is not exported (for example, the most simple function in the package, `max3`), I get the following error message:

```
> setwd('............./AnthropMMD/')
> library(devtools)
> devtools::load_all()
Loading AnthropMMD
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
  method         from 
  [.quosures     rlang
  c.quosures     rlang
  print.quosures rlang
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'car':
  method                          from
  influence.merMod                lme4
  cooks.distance.influence.merMod lme4
  dfbeta.influence.merMod         lme4
  dfbetas.influence.merMod        lme4

Attaching package: ‘testthat’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:devtools’:

    setup, test_file


> test()
Loading AnthropMMD
Testing AnthropMMD
✔ |  OK F W S | Context
✖ |   0 1     | max3
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
test-max3.R:5: error: max3 gives correct answer
could not find function max3
```

I found [on this thread](https://github.com/r-lib/covr/issues/301) that using `devtools::load_all()` before running the tests should fix the problem, but it did not work for me, and I guess I should have missed something.

What is the correct and complete set up one should follow to be able to test non-exported functions in an R package?

Thanks!

(NB: as I am not an Rstudio user, please do not make me any "Rstudio-specific" answer ;))

Comment: I don't find `max3` in your repo, where is it ?

Comment: `max3` is in the `int` directory not your `R` directory. Use `pkgload::load_code(path)` or `source(file)`  with the correct path/file

Comment: Oops, I didn't know that! But indeed, it works now ;) Thanks!